# I Need to install sdl 1.2.15 in mingw (Windows 64bit)

Tags: windows, mingw, sdl, sdl-1.2

Is there a way to install the old sdl 1.2.15 in mingw on Windows 10 for 64 bit. Everything I find is either only for 32 bit or for 64 bit but only for linux. I also need to install sdl gfx and sdl ttf.

Comment: Why you don't want SDL2?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have to use a Go framework wich need sdl 1.2.15 to run.

Answer (score 0):

SDL 1.2.15 builds fine under [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) using `./configure` and `make`.

Or you can just get the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) package (see https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL) using `pacman`.